# How to stop iAds from skewing the SKScene in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, iad

So I have added iAds to my application and I have done this very simply. By importing iAds into the ViewController.h and putting the following code into the ViewController.m file:

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
```

This works, however, when I the add loads the screen is squished. Where all of the images and sprites become shorter.

Is there any way the add can just be overlaid on top of the SKScene? so that is does not affect the elements below – so that it stops the squishing?

Also, is there a way to only have the banner ads run in certain SKScenes or when a BOOL is changed from YES to NO?

**UPDATED**

**Code from my project:**

```
#import "XYZViewController.h"
#import "XYZMenuScene.h"
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@implementation XYZViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [XYZMenuScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    //iAds Enabled
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

This is all I have in terms of the iAds. It makes the entire scene push upwards to make room for the ad banner. Where I want it to just be over the scene and not push anything. So it covers, instead of pushes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overlay you can set the Z position of the banner higher than the rest of the content by default it's 0.

eg:

```
    banner.layer.zPosition=2;
```

but I believe the iAd framework has built in method thats you can override to control when the ads must display and when they shouldn't and give you much more control.
Specific methods are called when the ad is available,and like you said you make the ads appear only when a boolean value is 1 or 0.

eg:

```
  - (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
   {

  if(showADS==1)
  {
if (!self.bannerIsVisible)
{  
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
 // Assumes the banner view is just off the bottom of the screen.
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
}
}
 else
  {NSlog(@"No ads");}

}
```

check apple's documentation regarding this,they are really helpful
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html

But let give a complete example.
The banner instance is only available in you iAd Methods not outside them.
In your view did load method:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad

    { 

     self.canDisplayBannerAds=YES;

     }
```

This method is called when the ad is loaded,in this method specify the position of the ad

```
    - (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
      {
         banner.layer.zPosition=2;
        /*do all the additional like checking is the boolean is 1 or 0 etc.*/ 

      }
```

If you are working with iAd and sprite kit,you need to call methods in your view controller from the scene class to do all the ad work.

Suppose you have a method  named **checkAD** in your view controller that checks if the ad should shown or not etc..

You can call this method from your scene class by using this code

```
if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(checkAD)]){

    [self.delegate checkAD];
}
```

Comment: One question, how do you get the banner variable? @Prithiv

Comment: The banner instance works only inside the iAd methods,this is automatically done for you.
One thing is it only works in the iAd methods,you can just set the position very time you want to display the ad

Comment: I mean for the zPosition. Do I have to create the banner variabel?

Comment: I was talking about the zPosition.Set the zPosition in side the iad methods.

Comment: I don't understand? I put the self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES; in the ViewController.m file

Comment: I think the problem you are facing is that your not able to call methods that are in your view controller from scene

suppose you have a method named checkAD in your view controller 
you can call checkad from your scene class.

    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(checkAD)]){
  
        [self.delegate checkAD];
    }

Comment: Whenever the iAd loads it still squishes all of the content upwards. So whenever I look at the nodes and fps strings at the bottom it is not on top of the iAd.

Comment: Post some code regarding this from your project.To know  what the problem actually is.

Comment: I have updated the problem. Hopefully this enables you to solve my problem :)

Comment: I implemented banner ads in one of my apps that i'm working on currently and the banner seems to push all the elements.Although it is quite a good feature sometimes it's not needed.
Apple should have some property to control this.
I guess you have to try it the old school way

**This was how banner ads were before iOS 7**
You can make a banner view in storyboard and put it in your view controller view,then make a instance of it in your ViewController.h file[press control and link it in the .h file].
Using this instance you can control every aspect of the banner view.
This is very easy to do.

Comment: in the iAd methods you can control the banner using the instance you made in your.h file

Comment: I don't know how to exactly, but I found in the development libraries that Apple offers that there is a perfect example of what I want to do: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010198-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

Please download the source code and then run the folder named:Basic Banner in the iAdSuite folder. As you will see the banner ad does not affect the view in terms of skewing. This is what I want to know how to do, but I don't know which part of the code within the source code does it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the SKSCene in a container View that might help. From my experience any Apple subclasses of UIViewController can do weird stuff when iAds are added through canDisplayBannerAds.